# Hebrew "shemen" versus Latin "semen"

Tags: etymology, latin, hebrew

**Is the etymology of the word "*semen*" (eng. "seed") in Latin connected to the hebrew word שֶׁמֶן "*shemen*" (eng. "ointment")?**

I've just read a [peculiar article](http://www.davidjayjordan.com/AnnointedWife.html) that attempted to make this connection:

> The word for "ointment(s)" here in the Hebrew is SHEMEN meaning "ointment, oil, fat, cream, fertility". This word is almost certainly the origin for the Latin word "semen" meaning "seed", from which we get our English word "semen".

The context is the "[Song of songs](http://www.scripture4all.org/OnlineInterlinear/OTpdf/can1.pdf)" book from the Bible. The coincidences are interesting: Song of Songs is an erotic poem, there is phonetic similarity between "shemen" and "semen", and the meaning "ointment" that could refer to sperm.

But then, this could just be a coincidence. Can anyone disprove that the latin "semen" is not derived from or related to the hebrew "shemen"?

Comment: You've got it back-to-front. The person proposing an etymology should present evidence to back it up, not the person disputing it. A rough phonological similarity and some tenuous semantic similarity are not evidence. Anyway the etymology of Latin /semen/ can be traced back to proto-Indo-European so that would seem to disprove the connection (unless you want to claim it was borrowed into pIE from proto-Semitic?).

Comment: Well, I'm not proposing the etymology, I'm asking whether the etymology this article proposed has good basis.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Latin *semen* comes from *sero*, "to sow", which in turn comes from the Proto-Indo-European *sē(i)-, "to sow". (The Latin *r* is from reduplication and rhotacism between vowels, in that order. The reduplication happened in Proto-Indo-European.)

The Latin suffix *-men* is related to Greek *-ma* as in *comma, stigma, telegram[ma], etc.*. It is quite common in Latin, as in *limen*, gen. *liminis* (English *sub-lime*), *omen, nomen*. It probably existed in Proto-Indo-European already, since it also exists in Germanic and Slavic; the ancestor of *semen* was probably formed in Proto-Indo-European, not in Latin.

Unless we could prove that Hebrew borrowed it from Latin or Proto-Indo-European, or that Hebrew had the same morphemes, I think it is safest to assume that this is a coincidence, as it is usually the case with resemblances across different linguistic families.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a layman in all this. Apparently it is a coincidence.

Comment: The suffix also occurs in English words such as "seam" (that which is sewn) and "gleam" (that which glows).

Comment: In Latin, its IE origin is not so obvious because of (1) rhotacism in a (2) reduplicated stem. However, in Modern (!) Russian, the verb is "se-jat'" and the noun is "se-mja" (NOM. reduced stem), "semen-i" (GEN.SG. full stem).

Comment: @AlexB.: Ah, I was wondering where the r came from (too lazy to look it up). Do you have any idea why its stem was reduplicated? This does not normally happen with non-perfective Latin verb stems. I also wonder where the p and the r came from in Greek sper-...

Comment: @Cerberus, in PIE there was a group of verbs that got reduplicated, and Latin sero "sow" is simply a reflex of this process. Sihler mentions the following verbs in Latin of this type: sido, gigno (cf. genui), sisto (cf. sto). Note: in Infectum, reduplication and zero degree (sero < *si-sH1); whereas in Perfectum there is no reduplication (sevi < *seH1-vi).

Comment: @AlexB.: Ah, yes, *gigno* and *sisto*, of course—why didn't I think of those? So it happened in PIE, that makes sense. In those verbs the root is obvious. I suppose it was just not productive in Latin? Perfective reduplication was quite productive in archaic Latin, I believe, as in *fefeci, poposci/peposci, memini, fefelli, peperi, steti* (probably), etc.

Comment: @Colin and Alex: I have added some information from your comments into the answers, thanks.

Comment: Very good. Also, שמן `shemen` "fat, oil" is related to Arabic Arabic: شَحْم `shaħm` "grease", so one would indeed have to go back to at least Proto-(West)-Semetic to find any purported common root with PIE.

Comment: @MarkBeadles: I.e. to the dark unknown...but it would be interesting to compare the Proto-Semitic roots. I just don't feel qualified to do so.

Comment: @Cerberus: but note that the PIE root has only one consonant. The other two are part of the suffix.

Comment: Latin "semen" comes directly from PIE see̯mn (сf Russian семя).

Comment: @Mark Beadles, where are you getting the connection between shemen and shaħm? Those don't seem to share anything other than the first consonant (I don't see how the M's can be related since in the Hebrew root that's the second consonant, in the Arabic root the third).

Comment: @Cerberus: Gk. sper- is an unrelated root; it may have some cognates in Armenian (about which Chantraine is somewhat dubious), but has nothing to do with *seh1-.

Comment: @Cerberus: Is there a greek cognate ma-stem to lat. sēmen? I instantly thought of greek ἧμα 'that which is thrown' because of its fitting semantics but it belongs to ἵημι.

Comment: @aorists: Chantraine says `*sē-` "to sow" is probably only reflected in the western Indo-European languages, so not in Greek; it notes, however, that some scholars believe there may have been some later contamination, in which case ἵημι would come from `*sē-` via some western Indo-European reflex.

Comment: @TKR: Ah, it appears the etymology of *speirô* is quite a minefield. Chaintraine says it comes from PIE `*sper-`, as you say, and Hofmann that it is related to *Spreu* "chaff". Duden says this word is related to the likes of *spray* and Dutch *sproeien*, root `*sp[h]er[ə]-` "to sprinkle", and possibly to *sprinkle*, Dutch *sprenkelen*; the Woordenboek der Nederlandsche Taal says the latter group of related Germanic words is from a causative *sprengen*, "to cause to spring", from *spring(en)*.

Comment: ... But the WNT says about the verb *springen*, "origin uncertain, perhaps from `*sp(e)rʰ-` "to hurry". Duden says *Spreu* is probably related to *Spur* "spoor" and its root `*sp[h]er[ə]-` "to hurry" is probably the same as `*sp[h]er[ə]-` "to sprinkle" above and related to *springen*. Latin *sperno* "to spurn" may be related to *spoor*.

Answer (score 10):

Hebrew šɛmɛn שמן “oil, fat” is a Semitic cognate of Arabic samn سمن “fat, butter” (with Semitic s1). It is not related to šaḥm شحم “fat, grease” (with Semitic s2 and ḥ) or to the IE words mentioned above.

It is true that šɛmɛn looks superficially like Latin semen, but the vowels of the former are the result of a specifically Hebrew development (Semitic qatl >  Hebrew qɛtɛl; so-called segolisation). If you posit a proto-Semitic *šamn- the similarity with the Latin word becomes considerably less.

Comment: Given that the PIE form was ***see̯mn***, the similarity does not go away.

Comment: There are two hypothetical possibilities. One is that Sem. *šamn- and IE *seh¹-mn have a common “Nostratic” ancestor. But in this case one ought to expect the laryngeal to have survived in Semitic. The other is that some borrowing has happened, but one would have suggest who specifically borrowed from whom. But in either case, the main difficulty is that *šamn- means “fat, grease” and that *seh¹-mn means “seed”. The semantics do not really match.

Comment: is the -mn suffix known in proto-Semitic or proto-Afro-Asiatic?

Comment: No, it is an IE suffix.

Answer (score -2):

The word for "seed" in PIE was ***see̯mn***. It indeed uses the -men- suffix (in zero-grade).

Comment: Sounds really interesting that you found the connection. Do you have any references to that?

Comment: There is no connection.