# Is there any relation between the Hebrew word שד for 'demon' and the English word 'shade' for ghost?

Tags: english, etymology, hebrew

A [שד](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%93_(%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%92%D7%99%D7%94)) (pronounced *shade*) is a demon or ghost, in Hebrew. In English, the word '[shade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shade_(mythology))' is used to mean ghost or demon in some places. (I find it in fantasy novels a lot.)

**Is there any relation?**

Comment: See also these questions: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/hebrew-shemen-versus-latin-semen, http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/the-origin-of-the-word-god, and http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8373/hebrew-to-english-connection-through-linguistics

Comment: שד isn't really pronounced *shade*, but [ʃɛd], which is closer to English *shed*.

Comment: @TKR. In Biblical/Classical Hebrew it is actually /ʃeδ/, which sounds even less like “shade”.

Comment: English 'shade' for demon is metaphorical for 'shadow of a dead spirit', so the etymology is [the same as that for shadow](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=shade). Do you know the provenance of 'שד'? Is it somewhere on the [AHD Semitic Roots list](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/semitic.html)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Probably not.

The etymology of English "shade" (newest to oldest) is something like:

- Modern English "shade"
- Old English *sċeadu* (shadow)
- Proto-Germanic **skađwaz* (shadow)
- Proto-Indo-European **sk(e)h₃-tos* (darkness)

There's decent evidence for this being a native Indo-European root; while it was most productive in Germanic, it has descendants in different parts of the world as well (Ancient Greek *σκότος*/*skótos*, Irish *scáth*, loaned into Finnish *katve*).

The main etymology of Hebrew *šed* that I've found is:

- Modern Hebrew *šed* (spirit)
- Aramaic *šēḏā* (demon)
- Akkadian *šēdu* (a male *[lamassu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamassu)* (protective zodiac deity))
- (Unknown preceding Proto-Semitic form - but see fdb's answer)

(Transcribing all of these because my computer does not like changing text direction mid-line.)

There doesn't seem to be any obvious connection between **sk(e)h₃-tos* and *šēdu*, in form or in meaning. This is more likely just a coincidence.

Comment: Hmm. Well, that's a pretty good coincidence.

Comment: @Mithrandir Linguistic coincidences are legion. They happen all the time. For that reason, the default position when encountering a linguistic coincidence is to treat it as just that: coincidental, and nothing more, until such time as evidence is produced to make a concrete connection. In other words, when you hit a coincidence, either ignore it or see what the already-established etymologies have to say (as Draconis has done here in their answer).

Answer (score 3):

Akkadian šēdu is probably cognate with Arabic saʽd “happiness”. Aramaic šēδā and Hebrew šēδ are most probably borrowings from Akkadian, with reversal of the meaning (“good spirit” > “pagan god” > “evil spirit”).The proto-Semitic form would then be *s1aʽd.

http://dukhrana.com/lexicon//lookup.php?p=748&l=0